# For /F keep errorlevel output of exe

Tags: for-loop, batch-processing

Hello i build a menu like this

```
Select a mod from list below or select an option[1-4]:

[ 1 ] [Start Uncooking]
[ 2 ] [Browse computer for cooked mod]
[ 3 ] [Change cooked mods list folder]
[ 4 ] [Exit]

Cooked mods list folder:
D:\Spiele\The Witcher 3 Wild Hunt GOTY\Mods\:

"all folders of the above folder in one line like":
Mod1
Mod2
etc.
```

And i normaly work with it like this:

```
call %wselectEXE% %menuTXT% "Quick Mod Tool Uncook Menu" "set userinput=%listfolder%$item" "Uncook Menu" /menu /oemlist /oemout /margin /cmdCenter /grid /fs=12 /dx=485 /dy=180  > %userinputBAT% 
if %errorlevel%==0 del %menuTXT% & del %userselectionBAT% & del %userselectionlistBAT% & cls & goto :QuickModToolsMenu
if %errorlevel%==1 goto :UncookMenu
if %errorlevel%==2 goto :UncookMenu
if %errorlevel%==3 del %menuTXT% & goto :UncookAction
if %errorlevel%==4 goto :BrowseForModunCookMenu
if %errorlevel%==5 goto :ChangeListFolder
if %errorlevel%==6 del %menuTXT% & del %userselectionBAT% & del %userselectionlistBAT% & cls & goto :QuickModToolsMenu
if %errorlevel%==7 goto :UncookMenu
if %errorlevel%==8 goto :UncookMenu
if %errorlevel%==9 goto :UncookMenu
if %errorlevel%==10 (goto :UncookMenu) else goto :UncookMenuSub
```

Now i replaced it with a for loop but im missing the errorlevel of wselect.exe.

I got a workaround for this like this:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"wselect.exe Menu.txt "Quick Mod Tool Uncook Menu" "$item" "Uncook Menu" /menu /fs=12 /dx=485 /dy=180 /oemlist /oemout /margin /cmdCenter /grid"`) do (set "modname=%%a") & set "userinput=%listfolder%%%a"
if "%userinput%" == "%listfolder%" del %menuTXT% & del %userselectionBAT% & del %userselectionlistBAT% & cls & goto :QuickModToolsMenu
if "%userinput%" == "%listfolder%Select a mod from list below or select an option[1-4]:" goto :UncookMenu
if "%userinput%" == "%listfolder%[ 1 ] [Start Uncooking]" del %menuTXT% & goto :UncookAction
if "%userinput%" == "%listfolder%[ 2 ] [Browse computer for cooked mod]" goto :BrowseForModunCookMenu
if "%userinput%" == "%listfolder%[ 3 ] [Change cooked mods list folder]" goto :ChangeListFolder
if "%userinput%" == "%listfolder%[ 4 ] [Exit]" del %menuTXT% & del %userselectionBAT% & del %userselectionlistBAT% & cls & goto :QuickModToolsMenu
if "%userinput%" == "%listfolder%Cooked mods list folder:" goto :UncookMenu
if "%userinput%" == "%listfolder%%listfolder%:" goto :UncookMenu
goto :UncookMenuSub
```

Is there a way to get back to orignal %errorlevel% output?

keep in mind goto_%errorlevel% is not an option here because if i would build like this i would have to define 255 jump labels (up to 255 errorlevel in wselect.exe)

But i only need 8 %errorlevel% to work with because every other should jump to the same procedure.

Basically i need to set jumpmarks for the first lines of Menu.txt (blanklines get ignored)

for all other lines i need the same jumpmark.

FYI My script works as intended but i like errorevels and hate my own solution :D

Answer (score 0):

You make it yourself too difficult with the for loop, the example provided with wselect gives a good example of using the menu in a loop.

the wselect.exe sets the errorlevel itself, no need to create or execute the batchfile. In it's most simple form the following works if you have menu.txt with the following contents.

```
Menuitem1   
Menuitem2
Quit
```

in the same folder

```
@echo off
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:menu
wselect.exe menu.txt "My menu title" 
set line=0
for /f "delims=" %%l in (menu.txt) do (
    set /a line+=1
    if !line!==%errorlevel% (
      set item=%%l
    ) 
)

goto item%errorlevel%

:item1
echo selected %item% with errorlevel %errorlevel%
goto menu
:item2
echo selected %item% with errorlevel %errorlevel%
goto menu
:item3
goto quit

:quit
```

Your for loop doesn't work for getting the errorlevel because the errorlevel is only known after the command has executed and the whole for loop is considered as one command, so you would only get the errorlevel of the previous call.
Instead, I enumerate the menu file to find the text at the line with number=errorlevel

Comment: That doesnt help.

I need the selected item in a string. 

Wselect can produce up to 255 errorlevel.

I only need an errorlevel of 8 lines from the first 10 lines.

Comment: I understand the first part and adapted my answer to reflect that, the last part of your comment I don't get

Comment: Im editing the question i think then you will understand my problem. 

By the way your code produce an errorlevel but im not getting how i should get the output from wselect.exe with your code.

Comment: not possible I presume because the reason I mentioned in my answer, you will have to choose between errorlevel and $item, you could also use a real scripting language like Ruby with a GUI framework like Shoes

Comment: Thank you. I think i have to use my own solution.